# Is there a way to recover data from a Hyper-V avhdx file with a broken chain?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10

I have inadvertently broken the differencing disk chain for a Hyper-V VM on Windows 10. It's not the end of the world, but it would be nice to get the data back off the last avhdx file. I tried the trick of renaming the extension and mounting the file but it won't mount. In Hyper-v Manager if I try to edit the avhdx file, Hyper-V Manager crashes with the following exception:

> Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.ClassDefinitionMismatchException:
>   Property 'MaxInternalSize' does not exist in class
>   'Msvm_VirtualHardDiskSettingData'.    at
>   Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.EmbeddedInstance.GetProperty[TType](String
>   name, TType defaultValue)    at
>   Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.VirtualHardDiskSettingData.get_MaxInternalSize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Wizards.EditVhd.ActionPage.SetPageLayout(VirtualHardDiskSettingData
>   selectedDisk, VirtualHardDiskState selectedDiskState, Boolean
>   reconnect)    at
>   Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Wizards.EditVhd.NamePage.FailureRetrievingSelectedVirtualDisk(VirtualHardDiskSettingData
>   diskSettingData, VirtualHardDiskState diskState, Exception exception)

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 2):

Stephen Owen at http://foxdeploy.com/2015/09/29/hyper-v-on-windows-10-how-to-fix-a-broken-vhd/ describes one way to fix this. It appears to be a bug in Windows 10.

> ... using PowerShell and the Hyper-V module to run Set-VHD, like so:
>
> `set-vhd -Path "X:\Virtual Machines\Virtual Hard Disks\VM01.vhdx" -ParentPath "X:\Server2012Template\Virtual Hard Disks\Server2012Template.vhdx"`